# How to initialize a array with determined values?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char

I'm trying to prepare a value list. Briefly:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 9;
int z = 43;

int myarray[80] = {x, y, z};
```

But as you know, it's a mistake. I have too many value and they have a special order. The array is like this at the moment:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 9;
int z = 43;

int myarray[80];

myarray[1] = x;
myarray[2] = y;
myarray[3] = z;
```

when I want to insert a value between `y` and `z`, I need to change all values order by plus `1` after `z`.

Comment: You do remember that array indexes start at zero? If you use `1` as the starting index for your array you effectively loose an element, and will be a very lonely wolf when everybody else uses zero-based indexing (and will be very confused by your code).

Comment: ofcourse i know it. But my point is different.

Comment: Maybe designated initialisers? `int myarray[80] = { [20] = x, [40] = y, [60] = z };`

Comment: The line `92 = myarray[2];` is not a valid one, did you mean `myarray[2] = 92;` ?

Comment: Yes, i couldnt fix it so i delete it. i meant   ` differentvalue = myarray[2]; `

Comment: The question title doesn't seem to match the question body much. Is the question "How to initialize a array with determined values?" or "Why do linked lists exist"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "insert" new elements into your array, you need to make space for it. That means you need to move the latter elements one step "up" in the array.

You can either do this moving by using a loop like

```
for (size_t i = 79; // Index of last element
     i > 2; // The index of the element you want to insert *before*
     ++i)
{
    myarray[i] = myarray[i - 1];  // Move previous element up one step
}
```

Then you can "insert" the new value at the wanted position

```
myarray[2] = new_value;
```

Instead of an explicit loop you could also use [`memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove):

```
// Move element 2 to become element 3, element 3 will become element 4, etc.
memmove(&myarray[3], &myarray[2], sizeof myarray - sizeof myarray[0] * 2);

myarray[2] = new_value;
```

<sub>[Note that the above `memmove` call is just written without testing, I could have gotten the size wrong]</sub>

No matter what you do, an explicit loop or calling `memmove`, you will lose the last element in the array (at index `79` for an 80-element array).

---

If you're going to do insertions like this a lot, or if you don't want to loose any elements, then an array is probably not the correct container type. A linked list would be a lot better.

Comment: thanks for your comment and labor. Moving is not problem actually.But As you think, sometimes i need to add a few values to different position.

Answer (score 0):

In C you cant add or remove the element from the array. You need to write your own functions like this

```
void insert(void *arr, void *val, size_t pos, size_t arraySize, size_t elemSize)
{
    char *startRef = (char *)arr + pos * elemSize;

    memmove(startRef + elemSize, startRef, (arraySize - pos - 1) * elemSize);
    memcpy(startRef, val, elemsize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what do you mean by insert. If by insert the size of the array changes (from 80 to 81), then you 
1) need to use dynamic memory allocated arrays: **int* myarray = (int*)malloc(80 * sizeof(int))**; 
2) before insert, you need to increase the size: **myarray = (int*)realloc(myarray, 81*sizeof(int))**; 
3) then move the content of the memory: start from 81 -- downwards

If you want to keep the size of your array to 80, then go to step 3.

Answer (score 0):

If your max value is less than 80 you can use the index of array to store a flag 0/1 (present/not present)

```
unsigned char myarray[80];
memset(myarray,0,sizeof(myarray));

myarray[x]=1;
myarray[y]=1;
myarray[z]=1;
/* x,y,z... must be <80 */
```

So array is always sorted without moving array items.

Answer (score -2):

This is correct syntax for array initialization with values:
`var a = new int[] {x, y, z};`

Comment: The OP changed the question to be about C, not C#.